# Android, how to make two buttons next to each other with the same width

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to place two buttons on the xml next to each other and I want them both to be the same size(half from the width of the screen) - this is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:weightSum="2">
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bAddDelete"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bMainMenu"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works well, but when im changing the text in java, the width is changing, how can I make them the same size?

Thanks

Comment: **but when im changing the text in java, the width is changing** - yes because you are using wrap_content

Comment: Oh lol, fail... forgot about this.. thnx

Comment: set layout_width to 0dp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you set the weight of the view then you shouldn't use any values for the width / height. Set the width of the buttons to 0dp. You also don't need android:weightSum="2"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bAddDelete"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bMainMenu"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks very much!